# ESP32 was connecting earlier but is not connecting to WiFi now with the same code

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm doing a project where I have to connect to a WiFi network. So, I've used this code for ESP32 to connect to a WiFi network -

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("XYZXYZ", "asdfghjkl");

  // Wait for WiFi to be connected
  uint32_t notConnectedCounter = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("Wifi connecting...");
      notConnectedCounter++;
      if(notConnectedCounter > 50) { // Reset board if not connected after 5s
          Serial.println("Resetting due to Wifi not connecting...");
          ESP.restart();
      }
  }
  Serial.print("Wifi connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

The code I mentioned above worked well but for some reason, it is not working now. Now when I power the `ESP32`, it gives out something like (or similar to) this-

`}⸮~⸮}⸮n~⸮~ֶ⸮}⸮⸮⸮n⸮~n⸮⸮]⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮D⸮b⸮⸮z⸮}⸮⸮⸮1]⸮⸮}⸮⸮~⸮⸮|⸮⸮~}⸮]⸮}⸮=~]⸮⸮]⸮⸮]⸮]⸮⸮n⸮⸮ ֎UvHX⸮.,⸮⸮a⸮⸮⸮]⸮⸮>]⸮>⸮]⸮]⸮n>⸮⸮⸮>>⸮]⸮⸮>]⸮]⸮⸮6⸮`

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your `Serial.begin(11520)` **speed parameter** is the same as `Serial Monitor` **speed parameter** value.

[image]